# How do we call "Caching in Template" for Play 2.1?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.1

We are trying to follow the "Caching in templates" example listed in http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/JavaCache and the compiler throws us an "`not enough arguments for method getOrElse`" exception message.

Our code in the template:

```
@play.cache.Cache.getOrElse("cached-content", 3600){
    test
}
```

So we decided to dig the API and apparently we still short of `java.util.concurrent.Callable` parameter. Does anyone know what should we pass in for that parameter?

Thanks

[Play 2.1.1 Javadoc](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/api/2.1.1/java/index.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it's because you are trying to use a Java API from a Scala template with the syntaxe of the Scala cache API. If you want to use the example from the documentation you need to write something like :

```
@import play.api.Play.current
@play.api.cache.Cache.getOrElse("key", 3600) {
    <h1>Cached content</h1>
}
```

the play.api package is the package for Scala APIs.

If you want to use the Java Cache API from a template, this API takes 3 parameters and you need to write something like :

```
@play.cache.Cache.getOrElse("key", new java.util.concurrent.Callable[String] {
    def call: String = "Cached content again"
}, 3600)
```

Comment: Hi Trevor, you are right. We have mixed up Scala with Java API. Thanks for helping us out :))