# Play Framework 2.5 cache excluding part of the template?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.5

I want to cache home page of my project. The problem is there is a search form with Csrf token in it. So caching whole page will break search functionality. What are solutions to this problem?

Comment: For example, [turn off CSRF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21096729/how-to-selectively-disable-csrf-check-in-play-framework-2-java) for Search form.

Comment: Yes, this is the one way but I try to find if it possible to somehow exclude part of the template from cache. There are situations when turning off CSRF is not acceptable

Comment: Another solution is not to cache all template (action result) but [part of it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455474/how-do-we-call-caching-in-template-for-play-2-1).

Comment: @MipH It would be great to have this ability but there is no info on this in [current documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaCache)

Comment: Check the link from my last comment...